# React-rte: displaying name for Align buttons at toolbarConfig

Tags: reactjs, toolbar, rich-text-editor, text-alignment, rte

I have a react rich text editor. I would like to display option toolbar.
I am finding the display name for align (justify) pharse. I tried to find document about that, but I do not get any useful information

For example: history edit will have the display name "HISTORY_BUTTONS"

```
const toolbarConfig = {
    // Optionally specify the groups to display (displayed in the order listed).
    display: ['INLINE_STYLE_BUTTONS', 
              'BLOCK_TYPE_BUTTONS', 
              'LINK_BUTTONS', 
              'BLOCK_TYPE_DROPDOWN', 
              'HISTORY_BUTTONS'],
    INLINE_STYLE_BUTTONS: [
      {label: 'Bold', style: 'BOLD', className: 'custom-css-class'},
      {label: 'Italic', style: 'ITALIC'},
      {label: 'Underline', style: 'UNDERLINE'}
    ],
    BLOCK_TYPE_DROPDOWN: [
      {label: 'Normal', style: 'unstyled'},
      {label: 'Heading Large', style: 'header-one'},
      {label: 'Heading Medium', style: 'header-two'},
      {label: 'Heading Small', style: 'header-three'}
    ],
    BLOCK_TYPE_BUTTONS: [
      {label: 'UL', style: 'unordered-list-item'},
      {label: 'OL', style: 'ordered-list-item'}
    ]
  }
```

I want to find the display name for align pharse.
[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found the solution I needed here
[on react-rte github](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/lib/EditorToolbarConfig.js)

So what you need to do is change your toolbarConfig into something like

```
 const toolbarConfig = {
  display: [
    "INLINE_STYLE_BUTTONS",
    "BLOCK_TYPE_BUTTONS",
    "BLOCK_ALIGNMENT_BUTTONS",
    "LINK_BUTTONS",
    "BLOCK_TYPE_DROPDOWN",
    "HISTORY_BUTTONS",
  ],
  INLINE_STYLE_BUTTONS: [
    { label: "Bold", style: "BOLD", className: "custom-css-class" },
    { label: "Italic", style: "ITALIC" },
    { label: "Underline", style: "UNDERLINE" },
  ],
  BLOCK_TYPE_DROPDOWN: [
    { label: "Normal", style: "unstyled" },
    { label: "Inline Title", style: "header-three" },
  ],
  BLOCK_TYPE_BUTTONS: [
    { label: "UL", style: "unordered-list-item" },
    { label: "OL", style: "ordered-list-item" },
  ],
  BLOCK_ALIGNMENT_BUTTONS: [
    { label: "Align Left", style: "ALIGN_LEFT" },
    { label: "Align Center", style: "ALIGN_CENTER" },
    { label: "Align Right", style: "ALIGN_RIGHT" },
    { label: "Align Justify", style: "ALIGN_JUSTIFY" },
  ],
};
```

for the display, save and import aligned data visit [this issue](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/issues/402)